# Excel - Tie two list together

Tags: excel, list, dropdown

I have two list in excel that need to be tied together so that when an item in the first is selected from a drop down (C2) it changes the cell next to it (D2) to the corresponding value.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use Vlookup for that. In cell D2 enter this formula:

```
=vlookup(C2,List!$A$1:$B:$31,2,false)
```